# Manual Controls(Prev and Next) on Javascript Image carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code that creates a slideshow with Javascript.

The HTML

```
<div id="buttons">
    <a href="#" id="prev">prev</a>
    <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
<ul class="slider">
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2"> <!-- random image -->
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3"> <!-- random image -->
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4"> <!-- random image -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

The Javascript

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
  var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
  var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
  var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds

  function slides(){
    return $slider.find($slide);
  }


  slides().fadeOut();

  // set active classes
  slides().first().addClass('active');
  slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

  // auto scroll 
  $interval = setInterval(
    function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
    , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
  );
});
</script>
```

This code automatically slides through the images.

I am am trying to add a previous and next button functionality to it, so that users can manually flip through the images. I would like to be an infinite carousel.

How do I do this with fade, as I have it now?

```
$('#next').click(function() {

}
```

**EDIT**

I tried this:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
  var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
  var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
  var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds

  function slides(){
    return $slider.find($slide);
  }

    $('.slider img:gt(0)').hide();

    $('#next').click(function() {
        $('.slider img:first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slider');
    });

    $('#prev').click(function() {
        $('.slider img:first-child').fadeOut();
        $('.slider img:last-child').prependTo('.slider').fadeOut();
        $('.slider img:first-child').fadeIn();
    });

  slides().fadeOut();

  // set active classes
  slides().first().addClass('active');
  slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

  // auto scroll 
  $interval = setInterval(
    function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
    , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
  );
});
</script>
```

Now the manual buttons work, but the automatic scrolling of the slides on interval doesn't work anymore, the slides only change when the buttons are clicked. How do I also keep my automatic slideshow functionality as it worked before?

Answer (score 1):

Try Like

```
$('.img-wrap img:gt(0)').hide();

$('.next').click(function() {
    $('.img-wrap img:first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.img-wrap');
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
    $('.img-wrap img:first-child').fadeOut();
    $('.img-wrap img:last-child').prependTo('.img-wrap').fadeOut();
    $('.img-wrap img:first-child').fadeIn();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/hHnX5/681/)

Comment: Please see my edits above. I tried this, and the manual buttons work, but now the automatic slideshow does not.

Answer (score 0):

Take the anonymous function out of the interval call, and make it a regular function, so that next,prev, and interval can call it, modify it to use a direction variable instead of a hard coded value. This will make it so we can control the direction in which the carousel goes with user interaction.

I added a second timer, `autoTurnTimer` to restart the automatic turn functions if there is no user interaction after 3 seconds (plus the initial interval time)

```
var $interval, autoTurnTimer;
...
function turnCarousel(direction){
    var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

    slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
    slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

    $i = $i+direction;
    if ($i >= slides().length  ) {
        $i = 0; // loop to start
    }else if($i<0){
        $i = slides().length-1; //loop to end
    }

    slides().eq($i).fadeIn($transition_time);
    slides().eq($i).addClass('active');
}
function startAutoTurn(){
    $interval = setInterval(
        turnCarousel.bind(null,1)
        , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
    );        
}
$("#next").click(function(){
    //Clears the timers so not to compete against
    //user interaction
    clearInterval($interval);
    clearTimeout(autoTurnTimer);
    turnCarousel(1);
    autoTurnTimer = setTimeout(startAutoTurn,3000);
});
$("#prev").click(function(){
    //Clears the timers so not to compete against
    //user interaction        
    clearInterval($interval);
    clearTimeout(autoTurnTimer);
    turnCarousel(-1);
    autoTurnTimer = setTimeout(startAutoTurn,3000);
});
```

Note you could refactor further so that the next and prev callbacks use a single function, and modify it so the automatic turn continues in the direction that was last used.

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/264pb/1/)